# Select WHERE IN and LIMIT by number of rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a table which looks like this

```
 userid  |  value   | time
    
    1        0          1
    1        1          2
    1        2          3
    3        5          4
    4        6          5
    1        9          6
    3        10         7
```

Using a select where in query I would want to select userd, value, and time but limit the total number of rows pulled for each userid

My SELECT query,

```
select userid, value, time from table where userid in (1,3) order by time desc;
```

This query outputs all the values like so

```
 userid  |  value   | time
    
    1        0          1
    1        1          2
    1        2          3
    3        5          4
    3        10         7
```

I would hover want to limit the number of rows for each userid to two to get an output like so

```
   userid  |  value   | time
    
    1        0          1
    1        1          2
    3        5          4
    3        10         7
```

I tried using limit but that limits the number of rows for the entire output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a rank query to limit rows per user

```
select userid, 
value,
`time`
from (
select *,
@r:= case when @g = userid then @r + 1 else 1 end row_num,
@g:=userid
from test t
cross join (select @g:= null,@r:=0) t1
where userid in (1,3)
order by userid,value,`time` desc
) t2
where row_num <= 2
```

Above query will give rank to each record for same user like user 1 has 3 records the they will assigned  rank as 1,2,3 and if user 2 has 2 records then rank will be 1,2 for user 2 and in parent query i am just filtering the records according to the rank that return only result where rank is less than equal to 2 for for each user only 2 rows with rank 1 and 2 will be returned

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f28f/3)

Comment: can you explain. and it this expensive.

Comment: @user3569964 see my updated answer and yes it can b expensive if you have too many rows for user 1,3 but you also need to index your `userid` column

Comment: If that's the case what would be the fastest and most effecient way to select the lastest 3 values for a group of userids. I see a lot of social network show like last 3 post by a group of users.

Comment: @user3569964 other RDBMS have built in functions like [`ROW_NUMBER `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to calculate rank for row like SQL-Server,Postgre Oracle and other but unfortunately Mysql don't have these window functions so doing this type of query in Mysql i have shown in my answer